# Как добавить модель формата Wavefront OBJ в android-приложение без сторонних фреймворков, библиотек и пр

Tags: android, 3d, opengles

Осваиваю OpenGL ES 2.0. Как загрузить примитивы (точки, линии, треугольник) я знаю. Искал статьи по данному материалу и ничего не нашёл. Как можно загрузить модель в приложение, хотя бы с NDK

Comment: OBJ это текст, надо его прочесть, распарсить в числа и использовать числа для получения модели. Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос точнее. Что именно вам непонятно, что вызывает сложности?